# What is the analytical test to run in case of 1 measure for three groups?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova, computational-statistics

I have this case where the data look like that

```
Trial Person 1  person 2
1         4.7.         3.8
2         7.1.         6.3
3         5.4.         4.5
```

I want to see if there is variations WITHIN each person measurements. I want to do this in R. I found the test that supposed to do this is repeated measure ANOVA with levene's modification.

I use R and no code is working for me as it always requires multiple observations and I have only one. Please suggest a test and code for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is arranged in *unreplicated complete block design*.

For this design, you can use a one-way anova with blocks, or the nonparametric tests Friedman or Quade.

Because you have a repeated measures design, it is better to use a repeated measures analysis or a mixed model.  If your case, it is possible to use a mixed model.

For whichever model or test you use, please be sure to understand its assumptions.

I'm assuming in the following example that you have only three trials, but have multiple people.

I arranged the data in long format.

Note that you need to tell R to treat *Trial* as a factor variable and not a numeric variable.

```
### Examples from 
###    http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_06.html
###    http://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_11.html
###    http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_07.html

Input =("
Trial Person      Measurement
1     Person.1    4.7
2     Person.1    7.1
3     Person.1    5.4
1     Person.2    3.8
2     Person.2    6.3
3     Person.2    4.5
1     Person.3    10.8
2     Person.3    13.3
3     Person.3    12.5
1     Person.4    8.0
2     Person.4    9.3
3     Person.4    8.5
1     Person.5    2.7
2     Person.5    7.1
3     Person.5    5.4
1     Person.6    2.8
2     Person.6    6.3
3     Person.6    4.5
")

Data = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)

Data$Trial = factor(Data$Trial)

str(Data)
```

*Person* could be treated as fixed-effect block, though this is an antiquated approach.

```
if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}

model.1 = lm(Measurement ~ Trial + Person, data=Data)

library(car)

Anova(model.1)

hist(residuals(model.1))

plot(predict(model.1), residuals(model.1))
```

The relevant nonparametric test is Quade test.  If there were more than, say, 5 groups, Friedman might be used instead.

```
model.2 = quade.test(Measurement ~ Trial | Person, data=Data)

model.2
```

A better approach would be to use a mixed-effects model with *Person* treated as a random block.

```
if(!require(lme4)){install.packages("lme4")}
if(!require(lmerTest)){install.packages("lmerTest")}

library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

model.3 = lmer(Measurement ~ Trial + (1|Person), data=Data)

anova(model.3)

rand(model.3)

hist(residuals(model.3))

plot(predict(model.3), residuals(model.3))
```

We can also run a post-hoc comparison of least-square means.  Note that because the design is balanced, the least-square means for groups will equal the arithmetic means.

```
if(!require(lsmeans)){install.packages("lsmeans")}

library(lsmeans)

leastsquare = lsmeans(model.3 , pairwise ~ Trial)

leastsquare$lsmeans

CLD = cld(leastsquare, Letters=letters)

CLD
```

And a plot of the results.

```
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}

CLD$Group = gsub(" ","",CLD$.group)

ggplot(CLD,
       aes(x     = Trial,
           y     = lsmean,
           label = Group)) +

   geom_point(shape  = 15,
              size   = 4) +

    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin  =  lower.CL,
                      ymax  =  upper.CL),
                      width =  0.2,
                      size  =  0.7) +

    geom_text(nudge_x = c(0, 0, 0),
              nudge_y = c(4, 4, 4),
              color   = "black")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative comment. @Sal Mangiafico

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a book or any source I can go through to find answers about this or similar issues?

Comment: A textbook on "design of experiments" or "design and analysis of experiments".

Comment: @Omar113Omar , if my answer addresses the question sufficiently, please mark it as the accepted answer and upvote it. If not, please state the concerns in comments so that they can be addressed.